# How do I create a sub-layout to remove duplication from page code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, layout, nested, erb

I am building an application where seven of the pages are static, look almost the same and share the same controller, `StaticPagesController` In `StaticPagesController` I have just defined 7 empty actions that correspond to the names of the views in the `static_pages` directory.

All of the static pages will be based on the general application layout (`layouts/application.html.erb`, comprised of header and footer) and they will all contain a "hero unit" (a big banner with a picture) at the top and, below it, two columns. The first column will contain a paragraph of text that will be different on each page, and on the second column I will render a collection of ActiveModel objects (a different sub-set of objects will be shown on each page, but I'd like to be able to write the rendering code only once).

### Question

**What I would like to achieve** is a layout that inherits the header and footer from `layouts/application.html.erb` and allows me to only write the code that will change between each page and avoid duplicating the structure, the hero rendering and the collection rendering.

### My (probably wrong) solution

I have found a way to do this that works, but after reading the Rails guide about [nested layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) I'm a bit confused and I'm not really sure if it's the right way to do it. Here is how I did it:

I created `layouts/static_page.html.erb` with the following code:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/hero', locals: { big: true, big_text: hero_big_text } %>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <%= yield :introduction %>

      <%= render 'hook_button' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 bo-offers-col">
      The @collection will be rendered here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first line renders the hero passing a few locals to it, including one of them which has to be defined in the views. The rest of the code creates the two columns and yields the `introduction` code in the first one and is supposed to render the @collection object (which will be defined in the controller) in the second one.

Here is what one of the views contains:

```
<%# Page title %>
<% provide :title, "Page title" %>

<%# Specify the content %>
<% content_for :hero, yield(:title) %>

<% content_for :introduction do %>
  <h2>Page subtitle</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris congue fermentum quam a lacinia.</p>
  <p>Maecenas at sapien ut risus congue sodales eget quis enim. Etiam pulvinar nulla non libero lobortis vulputate. Aliquam convallis sapien nec velit sagittis molestie. Morbi porta pulvinar varius. Donec nec velit at nisi ultrices commodo viverra eu enim.</p>
<% end %>

<%# Render the stuff %>
<%= render template: 'layouts/static_page', locals: { hero_big_text: false } %>
```

First of all I provide a title which will be used both as the page `<title>` and as the text inside the hero. I use `content_for` to also provide the content of the first column.
Finally, I use `<%= render template: 'layouts/static_page', locals: { hero_big_text: false } %>` to render the template I defined earlier, passing the local I use to decide which type of hero to display (used in the hero partial).

This solution works, but I'm unsure whether it's semantically correct or if there are any better ways to do this. I haven't managed to find any documents or questions addressing this exact issue and I'd like to know if there are any better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using partial layouts here to simplify a little over the many different `content_for` calls. So do this from your view file

```
<%= render layout: 'hero_layout', locals: { hero_big_text: false } do %>
  <h2>Page subtitle</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris congue fermentum quam a lacinia.</p>
  <p>Maecenas at sapien ut risus congue sodales eget quis enim. Etiam pulvinar nulla</p>
<% end %>
```

And then instead of using `layouts/static_page.html.erb` create the partial layout referred to in my above code at `app/views/application/_hero_layout.html.erb` with code like this:

```
<%= render partial: 'hero', locals: { big: true, big_text: hero_big_text } %>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <%= yield %>

      <%= render 'hook_button' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 bo-offers-col">
      The @collection will be rendered here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that using a `shared` folder for partials isn't really the right way to go anymore. Instead, you can use [template inheritance](http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance?view=asciicast). So the `hero` partial would be picked up from your template inheritance path. Which probably means you'll need to have it located at `/app/views/application/_hero.html.erb` but that's up to the specifics of your app.